# SSLHandshakeException : Remote host closed connection during handshake

Tags: java, web-services, ssl, sslhandshakeexception

The forums are full with this question but I can't find a solution.
I try to connect a WS but without any success.
I tried to update cacerts file with no effect.

The log are :

```
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
%% No cached client session
*** ClientHello, TLSv1
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1507108654 bytes = { 133, 135, 81, 148, 186, 186, 146, 23, 28, 240, 158, 152, 139, 167, 209, 225, 54, 253, 112, 118, 61, 112, 140, 214, 149, 198, 197, 219 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5, SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
***
[write] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 75
0000: 01 00 00 47 03 01 5A D5   A7 2E 85 87 51 94 BA BA  ...G..Z.....Q...
0010: 92 17 1C F0 9E 98 8B A7   D1 E1 36 FD 70 76 3D 70  ..........6.pv=p
0020: 8C D6 95 C6 C5 DB 00 00   20 00 04 00 05 00 2F 00  ........ ...../.
0030: 33 00 32 00 0A 00 16 00   13 00 09 00 15 00 12 00  3.2.............
0040: 03 00 08 00 14 00 11 00   FF 01 00                 ...........
http-8080-1, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 75
[Raw write]: length = 80
0000: 16 03 01 00 4B 01 00 00   47 03 01 5A D5 A7 2E 85  ....K...G..Z....
0010: 87 51 94 BA BA 92 17 1C   F0 9E 98 8B A7 D1 E1 36  .Q.............6
0020: FD 70 76 3D 70 8C D6 95   C6 C5 DB 00 00 20 00 04  .pv=p........ ..
0030: 00 05 00 2F 00 33 00 32   00 0A 00 16 00 13 00 09  .../.3.2........
0040: 00 15 00 12 00 03 00 08   00 14 00 11 00 FF 01 00  ................
http-8080-1, received EOFException: error
http-8080-1, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
http-8080-1, SEND TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, description = handshake_failure
http-8080-1, WRITE: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
[Raw write]: length = 7
0000: 15 03 01 00 02 02 28                               ......(
http-8080-1, called closeSocket()
http-8080-1, called close()
http-8080-1, called closeInternal(true)
```

Thanks for you help

Comment: The server is refusing your client. You need to check what the server allows : if it is on Internet, check with SSLLabs, if it is in Intranet check with openssl commands.

Comment: Just an extra info. It's working using java8 but not with java 6 or 7.

Comment: Which precise versions ?

Comment: 6u45 for the moment

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most probably the server has disabled TLS 1.0 (and you're talking TLS 1.0 as seen in the sequence bytes *47 **03 01** 5A*), or it is waiting for the SNI extension which is absent.

About Java 6, only 6u111 will allow anything better (TLS 1.1) than TLS 1.0, and 6u121 will allow TLS 1.2. Have a look at the [Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#SupportClasses). Because of the *TLS version intolerance* problem, it's still unsufficient, and only a system property will enable it for good, as explained in the [Release Notes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/overview-156328.html#6u115-b32) :

> TLS v1.2 is now a TLS protocol option with this release. By default,
>   TLSv1.0 will remain the default enabled protocol on client sockets.

For this reason, a couple of system properties to try :

- `-Djdk.tls.client.protocols="TLSv1.2"` (prerequisite : 6u121 / 7u95)
- `-Dhttps.protocols="TLSv1.2"` if your code is using HttpsURLConnection

Your *ClientHello* is correctly formatted but it doesn't contain any extension (particularly the SNI). This is why it looks so short (*bytes = 80*). The SNI is enabled by default starting with 6u121 (if I'm right). Both causes that I see should be solved with the adequate Java version.

Comment: Semi-nit: you need 7u95 for the sysprop, but 1.2 protocol is available by calling `SSLSocket|SSLEngine.setEnabledProtocols` on all updates back to '7u0'. Similarly `https.protocols=TLSv1.2` (if `HttpsURLConnection`) works on all updates of 7, but only recent paid updates of 6.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Thanks for this info. The question doesn't say if he is coding anything with the JSSE or only using libraries relying on it. Maybe should we ask more often about this.